# myFile.exists() not working logically in Android

Tags: android, file, file-io, android-contentprovider

I have a section of code that is supposed to check if an mp3 file is stored in the SD card on the MediaStore.Audio.Media content provider

the problem is that no matter the situation.  Either if the file with the pathname stored in variable "audioFilename" exists on the SD card or not.  it always returns "this file does not exist" as the result.  Despite the fact that the variable audioFilename has the String path name stored in it "/mnt/sdCard/Music/Jungle.mp3", and this MP3 file is actually on the SD card. Easy to prove with a Toast message and a check of the SD card contents.

I probably have an error in the use of File or Environment classes.  Can anyone see a problem in the code shown here?

```
 // toast message to prove that the audioFilename is not null,
 // message displayed is the string, "File name: /mnt/sdCard/Music/Jungle.mp3"

 Toast.makeText(Editor.this, "File name: " + audioFilename,
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 // the code below always returns "this file does not exist"

 File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "audioFilename");

 if(myFile.exists()){

 Toast.makeText(Editor.this, "<<<< this file exists, it is: "+audioFilename+" >>>>",
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 } else if(!myFile.exists()){

 Toast.makeText(Editor.this, "<<<< this file does not exist >>>> ",
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 Toast.makeText(Editor.this, "audio file name is: "+ audioFilename,
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: try to make the first Toast display the actual location being checked instead of what you expect it to be.  Don't toast `"File name: " + audioFilename` instead do `extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "audioFilename"`

Comment: thank you for this response.  I tried this in my Toast message and it really helped me figure out why my code was not working.  With out this I would not see the cause of the problem clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try to change this line**

```
File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "audioFilename");
```

**with**

```
File myFile = new File(audioFilename);
```

I have run test with the same code and it is working well.

**Here is the code I test with :**

```
String audioFilename =  "/sdcard/NewFolder/test1.jpg";

Toast.makeText(SimpleTest.this, "File name: " + audioFilename,
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

// the code below always returns "this file does not exist"

File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myFile = new File(audioFilename);

if(myFile.exists()){

    Toast.makeText(SimpleTest.this, "<<<< this file exists, it is: "+audioFilename+" >>>>",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} else if(!myFile.exists()){

    Toast.makeText(SimpleTest.this, "<<<< this file does not exist >>>> ",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

Toast.makeText(SimpleTest.this, "audio file name is: "+ audioFilename,
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: yes this is RIGHT ON.   In my code I was using  extStore.getAbsolutePath() and as you pointed out, is the problem. When I did that the full string was "/mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/Jungle.mp3"  the repeated twice /mnt/sdcard/ is why it did not work.    Now it works great.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure have import java.io.File?

Try with :

```
String pathsd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/";
// so var pathsd will return "/mnt/sdcard/"
// then you must sure var audioFilename is Music/Jungle.mp3
File myFile = new File(pathsd + audioFilename);
```

Or are you sure with your path? if you not sure you can try give direct string path.

```
File myFile = new File("/mnt/sdCard/Music/Jungle.mp3");
```

Comment: this is the direction i think the problem is coming from.  i am not sure if i am using the file constructor correctly "extStore.getAbsolutePath() + audioFilename"  part of it i don't realy understand.   i will try this and see if it works.  "File("/mnt/sdCard/Music/Jungle.mp3");"

Comment: Hmmm if you want to get path sdcard, you can use Environment.getExternalStorageState(), so will return /mnt/sdcard

So you can try, example file there is /mnt/sdcard/tes.mp3 :
String pathsd = Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/";
String filename = "tes.mp3";
File myFile = new File(pathsd+filename);

OR

String pathsd = "/mnt/sdcard/";
String filename = "tes.mp3";
File myFile = new File(pathsd+filename);

Comment: the second part of your response is correct.  i gave you an upvote for that.  Pratik's answer above went directly to the cause of the problem . as you said.  File myFile = new File("/mnt/sdCard/Music/Jungle.mp3");   works well putting the string or string variable directly in there,  without the "exStore.getAbsolutePath()" added to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add permission in AndroidManifeast file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Edit :**

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myFile = new File(extStore+ "/Music/Jungle.mp3"); <---- try this
```

Comment: good, answer and observation,  however I already added that line to the manifest before asking the quesiton.  i should have mentioned that.  I will try to referesh the project, rebuild R.java generated files and see if that will work. sometimes the xml files get stuck and don't update

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to hazard a guess and assume that you are using a physical device to test your application.  If this is true, your external storage may not be mounted (since you're using USB storage with the computer) so the file really doesn't exist according to the system.  Try testing your code without the USB cord plugged in.

**EDIT:**
Remove the quotes around "audioFilename".

```
File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "audioFilename");
```

to

```
File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + audioFilename);
```

Comment: that is a good guess,  i have had that problem before.  but now i tried it unplugged.  and it still shows "file does not exist" despite the fact that the file is on the SD card

Comment: good catch.  that was also an error I did not notice.  If i needed to use the exStore.getAbsolutePath() it would not have worked because of the quotes.  however for my code using the exStore.getAbsolutePath() in itself is an error, so the error you pointed out is like second dimension of error below the original error.  or error squared